# border-radius и oveflow: hidden

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, как сделать, чтобы черный квадратик не обрезался по overflow: hidden и чтобы углы скруглились, спасибо

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вообще вопрос, довольно странный, т.к. свойство `oveflow: hidden` как раз означает "скрыть все что выходит за пределы". Вы ставите свойство "скрыть все что выходит за пределы" и спрашиваете, как сделать, чтобы " то,что выходит за пределы не было скрыто", самый логичный ответ - убрать это самое `overflow: hidden`. Вам здесь дали несколько ответов, предлагаю принять один из них, или отредактировать свой вопрос(пояснить можно ли убрать свойство `overflow: hidden` или нет)

Comment: Проблема в том, что с помощью overflow: hidden;  я хотел сделать скругления у .block1, .block2, а так как они выходят за рамки .block, то скруглений без overflow я не увижу, ниже дали ответ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без `overflow: hidden`

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px 100px;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0 ;
}
.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавив к .block свойство padding:

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 100px 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 30px 0 0;
}
.block2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
.block1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}
.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ошибочно, border-radius верхний у `.block` тогда пропадает

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov тогда уберите просто Hidden.